# Magento2 - admin price input's are rounding value to 2 decimals

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.3, uicomponent, currency, rounding

This is a Magento CE 2.3.2 project

In this project we need to work with 4 decimals for prices. We have tried this https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal which works fine, all prices are printed with 4 decimals in frontend, calculations are fine, and values are registered with 4 decimals in database tables when updating data through import/export functionality, or saving a product in admin, if we enter 4 decimal values

We have only 1 problem, but a big problem. In admin, in **product edit page** the **html price input's** are showing the value **rounded to 2 decimals**. So if we have a product with a price 1000.9555 €, if some admin user changes just one single letter in product's description then the rounded price value which is shown in the input (1000.96) is sent to form & saved, overwriting it to 1000.9600 in database

We have spent some days trying to find which template / js is responsible to print that form element, with no success. Any tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may try the step below for this customization:

I assume you are using a custom module name "Company_MyModle"

**step 1)**

Create a **di.xml** file under ***MAGETNTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/Company_MyModle/etc/adminhtml***

File : **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
     <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="pricetab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Company\MyModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Price</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>    
</config>
```

**step 2)**

Create the file **Price.php**  under ***MAGETNTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModle/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Modifier***

File :  **Price.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\MyModle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
/**
 * Class Eav
 *
 * @api
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @since 101.0.0
 */
class Price extends AbstractModifier
{


     public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator        
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;        
    }


     public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        if (!$this->locator->getProduct()->getId() && $this->dataPersistor->get('catalog_product')) {
            return $this->resolvePersistentData($data);
        }
        $productId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();
        $productPrice =  $this->locator->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['price'] = number_format((float)$productPrice, 3, '.', ''); 
        return $data;
    }



    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {    
        return $meta;
    }


}
```

**step 3)** Run di.compile

Comment: Points for you. This worked like a charm :) I'll give you the points tomorrow (system don't allow to give them during the 1st day). Just one thing: after applying your code we have found a new issue: TierPrice renderer still show 2 decimals. Let me ask your opinion...  could we the follow same approach rewriting the existing modifier in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/TierPrice.php, right?

Comment: Easier than that, as modifyData is returning the whole product data in $data array we can manipulate there every field we need, not only price

Comment: Yes. You can also go with modifying the whole modifyData to take control of everything. Thank you.

Comment: Anybody got this working with magento 2.3? I tried above but nothing changes and the field is still rounded to 2 digits

Comment: Thank you, this is working perfectly in 2.4

Comment: @PritamInfo24 issue in code, when we create new product in admin.

Notice: Undefined property:  Priceformat\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Price::$dataPersistor in 39 line

Comment: Hi, @PritamInfo24 perfect solution it working 2.4.2
In my Editor its say undefiend property and undefind method for these line

$this->dataPersistor
$this->resolvePersistentData($data);

how can include in this file?

Answer (score 2):

If anybody stumbles across this in the future. Based on Pritam Info 24's answer we modified our Price.php class to also include the formatting for the tiered prices as such:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\MyModle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
/**
 * Class Eav
 *
 * @api
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @since 101.0.0
 */
class Price extends AbstractModifier
{


     public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        if (!$this->locator->getProduct()->getId() && $this->dataPersistor->get('catalog_product')) {
            return $this->resolvePersistentData($data);
        }
        $productId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();
        $productPrice =  $this->locator->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['price'] = number_format((float)$productPrice, 4, '.', '');

        if(isset($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'])){
             foreach($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'] as $key => $tierPrice){
                $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'][$key]['price'] = number_format((float)$tierPrice['website_price'], 4, '.', '');
             }
        }

        return $data;
    }


    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

need to override dependency file of priceCurrency interface by below way to change precision of price.

you can set precision of price using custom module.

create custom module with below step.

step2 : create `registration.php` file,

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Adamsmage_PriceCurrency',
    __DIR__
);
```

step2 : `app/code/Adamsmage/PriceCurrency/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Adamsmage_PriceCurrency" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_Directory"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

step3: `app/code/Adamsmage/PriceCurrency/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency" type="Adamsmage\PriceCurrency\Model\Directory\Currency" />
</config>
```

step4: `app/code/Adamsmage/PriceCurrency/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format">
        <plugin name="format-price" type="Adamsmage\PriceCurrency\Plugin\FormatPrice" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

step5 : `app/code/Adamsmage/PriceCurrency/Model/Directory/Currency.php`

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\PriceCurrency\Model\Directory;

class Currency extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
{
    /*
    * You can set precision from here in $options array
    */
    public function formatTxt($price, $options = [])
    {
        if (!is_numeric($price)) {
            $price = $this->_localeFormat->getNumber($price);
        }
        $price = sprintf("%F", $price);

        $options['precision'] = 0;

        return $this->_localeCurrency->getCurrency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
    }
}
```

step6 : `app/code/Adamsmage/PriceCurrency/Plugin/FormatPrice.php`

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\PriceCurrency\Plugin;

class FormatPrice
{
    /*
    * Returns an array with price formatting info
    *
    * \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format $subject
    */
    public function aroundGetPriceFormat(\Magento\Framework\Locale\Format $subject, callable $proceed, $localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
    {
        $returnValue = $proceed($localeCode, $currencyCode);

        $returnValue['requiredPrecision'] = 4;

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Than Run below commands.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

i hope its work for you.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question... It seems your proposal does the same as https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal does. But the question wasn't this, we asked about the issue with the admin renderer for price input