# Magento 2.3.2 - Admin product price - use 3 decimals / stop rounding too 2 decimals

Tags: magento2

Issue: Rounding product price issues when using prices excluding tax

Example:

Product price including tax should be 3.95, we use 21% tax rate.

Product price excluding tax on product is entered as 3.265 which is automatically converted to 3.27 by Magento admin. 3.27 * 1.21 = 3.9567 which is rounded to 3.96 by Magento. But we need the price to be 3.95 on the frontend.

Is there a way to have for example 3 digits on the admin product price?

Tried this but nothing happens / or is changed

[Magento2 - admin price input's are rounding value to 2 decimals](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281899/magento2-admin-price-inputs-are-rounding-value-to-2-decimals)

Answer (score -3):

use the **round** function of PHP to limit it to the 3 decimal places

```
echo round(3.9567,3);
```

output

```
3.957
```

**Edit**

Round up to two decimal places

```
$price = 3.9567;
echo floor($price *100)/100;
```

output

```
3.95
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, that the outcome is still 3.957 which will be rounded to 3.96 in the frontend

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: let me know, did it solve your problem

Comment: not useful for controlling prices in Magento.