# Magento2 - admin special price input's are rounding value to 2 decimals

Tags: magento2, product, price

Referring to [Magento2 - admin price input's are rounding value to 2 decimals](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281899/magento2-admin-price-inputs-are-rounding-value-to-2-decimals/304415#304415?newreg=6a214834560d4051bc6605ab27c6c36b)

There is a perfect solution made by https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/86273/melvin for saving tier prices with 4 decimals.

I was wondering if there is any solution to save special prices as 4 decimals as well?
The code that Melvin made in Magento 2 is in /app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Modifier/Price.php

And the code is:

````
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\DecimalPrice\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
/**
 * Class Eav
 *
 * @api
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @since 101.0.0
 */
class Price extends AbstractModifier
{
     public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        if (!$this->locator->getProduct()->getId() && $this->dataPersistor->get('catalog_product')) {
            return $this->resolvePersistentData($data);
        }
        $productId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();
        $productPrice =  $this->locator->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['price'] = number_format((float)$productPrice, 4, '.', '');

        if(isset($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'])){
             foreach($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'] as $key => $tierPrice){
                $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'][$key]['price'] = number_format((float)$tierPrice['website_price'], 4, '.', '');
             }
        }

        if(isset($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['special_price'])){
             foreach($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['special_price'] as $key => $tierPrice){
                $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['special_price'][$key]['price'] = number_format((float)$tierPrice['website_price'], 4, '.', '');
             }
        }

        return $data;
    }


    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Oh never mind, I think I got it. This code seems to be working on Magento 2 version 2.3.4:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\DecimalPrice\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
/**
 * Class Eav
 *
 * @api
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @since 101.0.0
 */
class Price extends AbstractModifier
{
     public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        if (!$this->locator->getProduct()->getId() && $this->dataPersistor->get('catalog_product')) {
            return $this->resolvePersistentData($data);
        }
        $productId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();
        $productPrice =  $this->locator->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $productSpecialPrice =  $this->locator->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice();
        $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['price'] = number_format((float)$productPrice, 4, '.', '');

        if(isset($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'])){
             foreach($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'] as $key => $tierPrice){
                $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['tier_price'][$key]['price'] = number_format((float)$tierPrice['website_price'], 4, '.', '');
             }
        }

        if(isset($data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['special_price'])){
            $data[$productId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['special_price'] = number_format((float)$productSpecialPrice, 4, '.', '');
        }

        return $data;
    }


    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }


}
```